# How do you compare multiple two dimensional list that are the same values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a connection or a pattern between multiple list. Say for example, if list "C" has the same values as "D" and D has the same values as "B"  i would like to return the matching values with a new variable and return the values that not in the matching values and create another variable. If this can be done can you use a list comprehension to solve this problem? Another example, Here is my list

```
B = [[3, 21, 27], [3, 7, 21, 27], [3, 7, 21, 27],
     [3, 7, 21, 27], [3, 21, 27], [7, 21, 27]]

C = [[[2, 7, 8], [4, 13, 15]], 
     [[2, 5, 6], [8, 11, 12]], [[4, 6, 9], [6, 10]]]

D = [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 7, 8, 10],
     [4, 6, 10, 16, 20], [2, 3, 12, 17, 20], [7, 11, 16, 17, 20]]
```

I would like my results to be:

```
[[[[2, 3], [8, 2, 7, 3], [], [], [2, 3], []],[[3,4], [], [7, 4], [], [3], [7]],[[3, 2, 5, 6], [3, 7, 2 ], [7, 5], [], [3, 2], [7]],[[3], [3, 7, 8], [], [], [3, 12], [7, 11]],[[3, 4, 6], [3, 9], [], [], [], []],[], [], [7, 10], [], [], []]]]
```

Then i would like to remove the blanks if possible.

```
[[[[2, 3], [8, 2, 7, 3], [2, 3]],[[3,4],[7, 4],[3], [7]],[[3, 2, 5, 6], [3, 7, 2 ], [7, 5],[3, 2], [7]],[[3], [3, 7, 8],[3, 12],[7, 11]],[[3, 4, 6],[3, 9]],[[7, 10],]]]
```

I have tried to use this code below, it works but only works if im trying to match "B" to "D". I'm trying to get "C" and "B" to Match "D"

`E = ([[[list(set(x) & set(y)) for x in D] for y in B]])`

Comment: can you provide a clean, simple example? what are the values for C, B, D and the expected output ?

Comment: sorry forgot to put that. Its been update . just in case here is my list `B = [[3, 21, 27],[3, 7, 21, 27],[3, 7, 21, 27],[3, 7, 21, 27],[3, 21, 27],[7, 21, 27]]
C = [[[2, 7, 8],[4, 13, 15]],[[2, 5, 6],[8, 11, 12]] ,[[4, 6, 9],[6,10]]] 
D = [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[2, 3, 7, 8, 9],[4, 5, 7, 8, 10],[4, 6, 10, 16, 20],[2, 3, 12, 17, 20],[7, 11, 16, 17, 20]]`

Comment: Your list C has one more nested level than the others, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Can it still work or is there another way around it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want unique value, set is indeed the way to go.

Adding one union step should do the job :

```
(set(B) | set(C)) & set(D)
```

Worth a try?

Comment: C having another list level, is indeed an issue.

Following your template, this exemple works with 2 levels lists

`E = ([[[list(set(x) | set(y)) for x in B] for y in C]])`
`F = ([[[list(set(x) & set(y)) for x in E] for y in D]])`